# Tentando pegar dados do banco MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Pessoal tô querendo criar uma função que me retorna um array da minha coleção do banco, mas preciso fazer isso usando o drive nativo do mongoDB, sem o mongoose, gostaria de umas dicas.
Já tenho um código, porém não funciona:

```
async function findAll(){
    let users = []
    connectDB().then( db => {
        db.collection('user').find().toArray()
            .then(
                usersDB => users = usersDB
            )
    })
    return users
}
```

função connectDB:

```
async function connectDB() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    console.log('conectado!')
    return client.db(db_name)
}

module.exports = { connectDB }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de você estar declarando a função como assíncrona (usando a palavra reservada, ou *keyword*, `async`), você não está usando da funcionalidade que esse tipo de função oferece pra esperar que o resultado seja obtido, antes de poder retornar a lista de usuários:

```js
async function findAll(){
    let users = []
    // isso é, praticamente, ignorado
    connectDB().then( db => {
        db.collection('user').find().toArray()
            .then(
                usersDB => users = usersDB
            )
    })
    // automaticamente retorna a lista vazia
    return users
}
```

Pergunta-se: *por que aquele trecho é ignorado?* Simplesmente, porque "não se pediu que esperasse pelo resultado". E como faz para "pedir que espere"? Através do uso do [comando `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Portanto, mesmo que essas *callbacks* fossem executadas, elas não teriam o efeito que se espera, já que elas já não mais estariam sendo esperadas.

Como resolver? Simples:

```js
async function findAll(){
    let db = await connectDB()
    let users = await db.collection('user').find().toArray()
    return users
}
```

Assim, ele esperará que retorne a conexão com o banco de dados, e depois disso, esperará que retorne a lista de documentos, e só então retornará a lista. E lembrando que onde essa função (ou método) for usada, deve-se fazer o uso, ou de `async`/`await` novamente, ou da forma que você estava tentando fazer com `.then()`.

**OBS.:** lembrando também que isso tudo faz parte do assunto de [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)!

Espero ter ajudado!